# jQuery animate() complete callback not calling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got the following code:

```
if ($newCardLoader != null) {
    $cardsContainer.animate({
        maxHeight: futureHeight + "px"
      }, 500, "ease", function() {
        $cardsContainer.classList.remove("clamp-height-large");
        $cardsContainer.classList.add("clamp-height-fit");
        console.log("done");
    });
}
```

The log and the style changes just don't happen.
I have seen several posts on this topic and followed all of them.

To me, it seems correct. Hope somebody can help be out!

Comment: `.classList.remove()` is a vanilla JavaScript API. Use the jQuery equivalent `.removeClass()`;

Comment: In order to attach **animate**, **$cardsContainer** must be a jquery element. However, classList is vanilla javascript. So there is an issue there. Also, above your if statement, I would test **console.log($newCardLoader)** to make sure it isn't null

Comment: First tip when debugging Javascript: open devtools and check the console for errors. I can see two issues in your code, which the above comments have alluded to.

Comment: @imvain2 good point, my mistake for not showing more. $cardsContainer is actually the first [0] element of a query, thus not a query but just vanilla. No errors are thrown and the animation works but it might result in an issue with the callback. Need to check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@imvain2 and @Rory McCrossan suggestions are correct.
$cardsContainer needs to be a jQuery object i.e.

```
$("#some-id")
```

Mine was wrongfully vanilla e.g.

```
$("#some-id")[0]
```

This mistake does not throw errors and the animation works anyway.
Only the callback does not work. This makes it hard to spot to thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following.

```
if ($newCardLoader != null) {
  $cardsContainer.animate({
    maxHeight: futureHeight + "px"
  }, 500, "ease", function() {
     $cardsContainer.toggleClass("clamp-height-large clamp-height-fit");
     console.log("done");
  });
}
```

See more: https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: toggleClass is super cool. Thank you for pointing that out! (I oftentimes find it hard with JS to know the most recent functions.)